# Finish an activity in android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have some sets of activity.

```
Home Activity -> Activity 1 -> Activity 2 -> Activity 3 -> HomeActivity
                 finish();      finish();     finish();

Home Activity -> Activity 1 -> Activity 2 -> Activity 3 -> Activity 4 -> HomeActivity
                 finish();      finish();     finish();     finish();
```

So now when I am on the final step that is on the `HomeActivity` if I press back button it again takes me on to the home activity.

How do I finish the home activity without disturbing the whole process? Any help appreciated.

Comment: you want to press the back button then do what ? go back where ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this flag with your intent in each activity

```
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

This will not launch home activity again . It will use the previous instance of you Home Activity and bring it to top.

with CLEAR_TOP  If the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.

You can refer this [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) to get more idea about flags.

Comment: Actually, this isn't completely correct. This will not use the previous instance unless you either specify `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` or the activity has `launchMode="singleTop"` declared in the manifest. Instead, it will finish all activities on the stack **up to and including** the previous instance of the specified activity. It will then **create a new instance** of that activity and launch it. You can see this yourself if you add logging to `onCreate()` in `HomeActivity`

Comment: yeah that is the what i want to say. I have wrote in my answer "this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent." so all methods of that activity will be called again

Answer (score 1):

while calling Activity 3 -> HomeActivity
                finish()

implement below code :

```
Intent i = new Intent(Activity3.this,HomeActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you switch from one activity to another by defalut onPause() will be called, if you dont want this activity(in your case home activity), just override onPause() in your home activity and call finish() in onPause().

Answer (score 1):

Allright whenever u call your `HomeActivity` just add this to your `Intent`

```
Intent i=new Intent(yourActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

This will clear any previous present activities stack. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

call finish on the first home activity as well. i.e when you start activity 'Activity 1' after startactivity() call finish also.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent(Activity3.this,HomeActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
HomeActivity.this.finish();
```